# How can I fix my code in order to determine if the entire string is alphabetical?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript and trying to make a function that compares a current letter of a string with the one succeeding it, repeating through the entire string to then determine if it is alphabetical. My if condition is what's wrong, but I'm not sure how I'd change it to make it work.

Also, I'd like to keep the structure similar to what I have if possible.

```
function is_alphabetical(string) {
  let result;

  for ( i = 0; i < string.length; i++ ) {
    if ( string[i] <= string[i + 1] ) {
      result = true;
    } else {
      result = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Not sure giving them a regex that will seem obscure will help much @CertainPerformance. Why to you want to check the letter with its successor if you only want to check whether they're ALL alphabetical? Don't you think you should work on a way to check if a letter is alphabetical independantly from others, and then call it in the loop?

Comment: Say your string has length 3, then for i = 2 you compare string[2] with string[3], string[3] is undefined and your inequality is false, ergo.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into localCompare function e.g.

```
"a".localeCompare("b")
>> -1
"a".localeCompare("a")
>> 0
"b".localeCompare("a")
>> 1
```

in your case:

```
if((string[i + 1]).localCompare(string[i]))
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

By keeping the structure similar as you asked, I think this solution works:

```
function is_alphabetical(string) {
  for ( i = 0; i < string.length; i++ ) {
    if ( string[i] >= string[i + 1] ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

```
function isAlphabetical(str) {
  // we iterate only while i<length-1 to avoid going out of bounds when doing str[i+1]
  for (let i = 0, n = str.length - 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (str[i] > str[i + 1])
      return false; // at least one letter is making it not ordered
    // else keep checking other letters
  }
  return true; // if we reached here, its ordered
}
```

Comment: Hint: if you learn how to debug a code in your browser's JS console you can make it execute the functions step-by-step so you can check the variables and see what the code is doing wrong. In chrome: F12 > copy-paste the code, enter > type the function name, enter > click the result > set breakpoint > in the console call the function with a value and see how it's executed.